# Combi boiler on 2nd or higher floor - how to tell if water flow and pressure is sufficient?

Tags: water-heater, water-pressure, boiler, hot-water

The combination boiler in my house has to be moved, and one idea is to put it in the loft space to free up a decent amount of space in the main part of the house. The house isn't big, so this would be very useful. The entire water system is being redone, so all I have is the mains stopcock connection right now.

I can measure the flow and pressure at the stopcock easily.

Can I use the measurements to assess whether I will lose much output from the boiler if I put the boiler in the loft instead of the ground floor, or what the effect will be if I put the boiler in the loft?

### Notes if useful:

I'm in the UK, so floors here are ground, first and second. The second floor is the house's roof space (loft). The house has central heating. The kitchen and bathroom are almost above each other at the back of the house, and there's a ground floor walk-in shower at the front of the house. All hot pipes will be heavily insulated.

If it helps, the effects of a loft location as I see it are: **Boiler directly above main areas of use**, so water has a shorter run and space is saved. **Won't affect piped cold water** as cold water to taps doesn't go through boiler. **Won't affect central heating** as the heating circuit is sealed and pumped, at worst an extra floor means installing a slightly more powerful pump. **Possible effect on hot water at shower, bath and taps?**, because water has to be drawn up to loft to be heated (maybe offset by a matching "syphon" effect as it falls down to the taps?). I'd like to have a good rate of hot water for taps + shower if I can, so this would be a consideration.

Comment: If the water is liquid at all stages of circulation, the weight of the water going up the pipe will equalize with the water going down, and it won't make much of a difference.  If vapor is involved, all bets are off, because water is heavy and steam is not.  You did say "boiler" after all...

Comment: Its a combi boiler - the heating system is a sealed circuit, and the piped hot water is... I'm not sure. Should be liquid at all stages, shouldn't it??